# Rider keeps unit tests in pending state forever

Tags: c#, testing, rider

I am using Rider version 2021.1.2 and I have observed a peculiar behavior from Rider lately which I did not notice before. What I am noticing is that when I have multiple tests project and I run the tests for both together in a single session, when it is done running tests for the first project, it puts all the tests in the second project in pending state and then all of those tests remain in pending state forever unless I quit the application. It just started behaving this like and I am not sure if this a known bug. Below is a screenshot for the reference:

[image]

Comment: I believe it would be best to report it with Help - Report a Bug in Rider and agree to attach logs.